# Why do Saturn's rings have the most ice in them?

Tags: jupiter, saturn, gas-giant, rings

From what I've read, Saturn's rings are the most visible because they have an icy structure that makes it so the light is more reflective. Why is that the case, and why do other rings of the gas giants have a mostly rocky structure, and why are the rings of Saturn more dense than those of Jupiter, considering Jupiter's gravitational pull must be much higher.

Comment: Where do you read that the rings are rocky? Except for the water-rich Saturn rings, WP does not report any definitive composition where's it would if known. Dark material could be polymerized organics.

Comment: "why do other rings of the gas giants have a mostly rocky structure" where did you read this? Reference please.

Comment: Regarding density, see: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/722/how-dense-are-saturns-rings

Comment: Some questions about planetary science [are on-topic here](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1366/12102) but this might be more likely to receive good answers in [Astronomy SE](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Given their relatively short lifetime and likely origin, the nature of the rings is probably just down to what sort of rock or snowball fell apart last, and how long ago it broke up. Might just be chance.